# Is it possible to calculate the hash of a string if it contains that hash?

Tags: json, hash, md5, sha1, fingerprint

Today I caught myself trying to create a JSON document like this:

```
{
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : 2,
    'hash' : (some hash value),
}
```

Where the value of `hash` is the hash of the JSON document itself.  Obviously, this isn't going to be easy because the value of the hash function changes the hash of the document.  I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do, but just for grins, I'm honestly curious if there's any way to do this.

So is there any way I can set hash to a SHA1/MD5 (or really any common hash/fingerprinting function) such that it is equal to the hash of the resulting document?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you want something on the lines of `h(hash) = hash`? That sounds about as hard as preimaging...

Comment: @Mystical - More like `h(string_that_contains_hash) = hash`.

Comment: It's still the same idea. It's probably at least as hard as preimaging a hash. So it's probably not what you want.

Comment: This comment has eight words and zero upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the problem of equivalent JSON documents.  In most cases, for example the documents:

```
{'a':1,'b':2}
```

and

```
{'b':2,'a':1}
```

are equivalent, but their strings would likely produce different hashes. This indicates a need to canonicalize equivalent documents to the same form before applying the hash function.

Another problem occurs in JSON documents that use the value 'hash' (or the key that will contain the hash) to mean something else, like:

```
{'a':1,'hash':'this is not a hash'}
```

How can such a document contain a hash, short of using a different name for the hash key?  Indeed, it seems not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Any document I've built with a built-in hash always excludes the hash itself from the calculation. For example, when building a textfile, the first line or last line is the hash value, and the remainder of the file is what gets hashed, like:

```
B23128AB
SomeTextHere
SomeMoreText
```

where Hash("SomeTextHere\r\nSomeMoreText\r\n") = B23128AB

I'd expect you'd probably need to do the same type of thing for your JSON object.

This is still safe, since if either the hash value or the other contents is corrupted (doesn't matter which one), then your validation routine will fail.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty closely related to finding a preimage of a cryptographically secure hash function and, therefore, I think the best you're probably going to do is to try a brute-force-based attack (start guessing hashes h and check whether f(xhy) = h  exhaustively until you find an h that works with your x and y or prove none exists).